# Как заменить svg в форме валидации bootstrap 5 на свои?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно заменить svg . Возможно ли с помощью js? https://getbootstrap.su/docs/5.2/forms/validation/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: DevTools не находит данный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить на свой `url` в css `background-image`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]